# Disable openapi-generator from overriding the controllers implementation to default

Tags: python, flask, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I have a project created with openapi-generator and a python-flask application is generated using the open api. I am using following command to generate my app.

`openapi-generator generate -i OpenAPI/api.yaml -g python-flask  --skip-validate-spec`

But this command override my already implemented controller implementations to the default. Is there a way to,

1. Skip the controllers that was not updated in this iteration and create only the new ones.
2. If not skip generation of controller python files

I have already used `.openapi-generator-ignore` and ignored the controller repository.

But i am looking for something better?

Answer (score -1):

I'm working on a project here which could helps you for generating openapi easily without have to execute or config anything just run your server. Here it is [flask-toolkits](https://pypi.org/project/flask-toolkits/)

the implementation is via your view function and its really flexible. Its inspired by FastAPI's openapi setup

```
from typing import Optional
from flask import Flask
from flask_toolkits import AutoSwagger, APIRouter, Body, Header, Query
from flask_toolkits.responses import JSONResponse

app = Flask(__name__)

auto_swagger = AutoSwagger()
app.register_blueprint(auto_swagger)

router = APIRouter("email", __name__, url_prefix="/email")

@router.post("/read", tags=["Email Router"])
def get_email(
    token: int = Header(),
    id: int = Body(),
    name: Optional[str] = Body(None),
    race: Optional[str] = Query(None)
):
    return JSONResponse({"id":id, "name": name})

app.register_blueprint(email_router)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

go to http://localhost:5000/docs

and here you go

[image]

Comment: Does this project generate the code and implementation if we provide the api definition?

Comment: the yaml? yes. once it launched can go to http://localhost:5000/openapi.json

Comment: No I want to generate the code based on the yaml. Not yaml based on the code. Is this supported?

Comment: does your project provide this support? Contract first design?